# Android.Gradle: Sign release apk and put on specific folder

Tags: android, gradle

Gradle 4.2, Android Studio 2.3.3.

My **app/build.gradle**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myproject"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.2.3"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['KEY_ALIAS_RELEASE']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['KEY_PASSWORD_RELEASE']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['STORE_FILE_RELEASE'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['STORE_PASSWORD_RELEASE']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
       release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}
```

If I want to create sign apk I use the next command:

```
gradlew assembleRelease
```

As result I get sign apk in the path = `\my_project\app\build\outputs\apk\app-release.apk`

OK. It's work fine.

Now I has some custom requirements:

1. Sign release apk
2. The resul apk name must be "**myproject_xxx.apk**", where ***xxx*** = **versionName**. So in this example result apk name = "**myproject_1.2.3.apk**"
3. The file "**myproject_xxx.apk**" must be in the directory: `my_project\result_apks\`

So to do all of this points I need to write my custom gradle task. I'm right?

Comment: Please create Apk with same name and define version inside manifest package will be same. And

Comment: have a look at this: https://meedamian.com/post/publishing-with-gradle/